# Petite-vue Init attribute in HTML script tag

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, petite-vue

I recently saw this `Vue.js` snippet by Evan You on Twitter, and I don't understand what the `init` attribute in the script tag does. I could not find anything about this on MDN or similar sites.

The `defer` attribute is clear to me.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/petite-vue" defer init></script>

<!-- anywhere on the page -->
<div v-scope="{ count: 0 }">
  {{ count }}
  <button @click="count++">inc</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's explained in the repo Readme file in the [Usage](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#usage) section :

> The `init` attribute tells `petite-vue` to automatically query and initialize all elements that have `v-scope` on the page.

and according to this [code snippet](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue/blob/8af9aab4d16fc89a7ab6aec672225c484d8f5414/src/index.ts) it's a custom attribute and it's used to mount the app if the script tag is present :

```
let s
if ((s = document.currentScript) && s.hasAttribute('init')) {
  createApp().mount()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @[Boussadjra Brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim) mentioned, `init` is a custom attribute used to mount the app in `petite-vue`.

**In addition to the point**, If you don't want the auto init, remove the init attribute and move the scripts to end of `<body>`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/petite-vue"></script>
<script>
  PetiteVue.createApp().mount()
</script>
```

Or, use the ES module build:

```
<script type="module">
  import { createApp } from 'https://unpkg.com/petite-vue?module'
  createApp().mount()
</script>
```

For More Info Refer : [Docs](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#manual-init)

Answer (score 0):

The `init` attribute according to the README file on the `petite-vue` repo instructs `petite-vue` that on the load of the page to immediately find and initialize all elements that have the `v-scope` as attributes on a that page.

However you can manually initialize `petite-vue` by omitting the `init` attribute and making sure the script tag you are initializing `petite-vue` in is at the end of the body tag `<body>` and then follow the docs on the initializing steps.

https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue#manual-init